# SSIS connecting to Oracle 10g Error

Tags: oracle10g, ssis

Hi I am trying to connect Oracle 10g(Source/Target) from ssis
using connection string as
Data Source=Qrgo;User ID=sy;password=sa;Provider=MSDAORA.1;
**Qrgo is Servicename**

getting error
Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. ORA-12520: TNS:listener could not find available handler for requested type of server

Please advise how to resolve this. Thanks

I have tried

1.tnsping

it is successful

2.Attempt a connection to the instance

Once you have proven that the tnsnames is talking to the listener properly, the next step is to attempt a full connection to the instance. To do this we.ll use sqlplus:

sqlplus [username]/[password]@
it is successful

but ,while trying to configure from ssis it is throughing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error: ORA-12520

Text: TNS:listener could not find available handler for requested type of server

Cause: None of the known and available service handlers for requested type of server (dedicated or shared) are appropriate for the client connection.

Action: Run "lsnrctl services" to ensure that the instance(s) have
registered with the listener and that the appropriate handlers are accepting connections.

Possible solution:

http://www.shutdownabort.com/errors/ORA-12520.php

Comment: try to run lsnrctl on cmd(windows xp) 
C:\>LSNRCTL
'LSNRCTL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I think you do not have LSNRCTL set in your path. Try to search for it in your box. Here's a succinct description of LSNRCTL - http://www.ucertify.com/article/what-is-lsnrctl-listener-control-utility.html | http://www.remote-dba.net/t_advanced_oradim_utility.htm